# When using textEntered I can't get the backspace key to delete last character of the string

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to create a text box a user an input data into, it is going fine, however, whenever I try to set up the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key to delete the last character of the string, it doesn't seem to work even though countless tutorials have showed me this way.

```
if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered)
{
    sentence += (char)event.text.unicode;
    //if (sentence.getSize() < 16) {

    // 

    if (event.text.unicode == 8)
    {

        sentence.erase(sentence.getSize() - 1, sentence.getSize());

    }
    text.setString(sentence);

    break;
    //}
}
```

Also, was wondering what would be the best way to stop the string from advancing 16 characters.

Comment: Is sentence a string? what is getSize()?, I've tested a code with a string and it works fine

Comment: yes, sentence is an sf::String and getSize() seems to be working fine . i think im missing something dumb can't find it tho :/

Comment: Oh, i used a std::string, nevermind, i'll try again

Comment: thanks for trying to help ! how did you use getSize() for an std::string?

Comment: i changed it to std::string and used .size() only and the same results. im sure it's going through the if statement because i have a cout print in console when it fires . >.< this should be easy maybe im just tired a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, its not that hard, you're going to feel weird after what i'm going to say ^^

```
if (event.type == sf::Event::TextEntered) {
    if (event.text.unicode == 8)
        if (sentence.getSize())//If the string doesn't have any char, don't do anything
            sentence.erase(sentence.getSize() - 1, sentence.getSize());
    else //Don't add any character when you delete one
        if(sentence.getSize() < 16)//Yeah, thats the best way to do it
            sentence += (char)event.text.unicode;

    text.setString(sentence);
    break;
}
```

If you were pressing backspace, your program was adding it to the string and then deleting it... so... it wasn't doing anything ^^

Comment: I wonder what happen when you hit backspace like a maniac... ;-)

Comment: Yeah, don't forget to check if your string contains at least one character when deleting. Edited

Comment: Your edit doesn't fix it. Now if the string is empty you'll add `8` to it.

Comment: Well, well, well...and he wasn't able to delete a char if the size was >16... damn